# Is it a nervous behaviour for dogs to "clap" their teeth?

Tags: dogs, anxiety

I apologise for the title vagueness but I can't think of another way to describe the behaviour. It is *not* teeth chattering if that means anything like human teeth chattering. I don't want to say "chomp" because it's anything but aggressive.

We have minded a dog for some acquaintances twice now, about a year apart. On this occasion, we have noticed that the dog seems much more timid than last time and has an odd habit of "clapping" her teeth.

By this I mean, with every interaction she makes this deep clicking sound that I am pretty sure is her chomping her teeth. The closest I can describe it is if you inflate your own cheeks and smack your teeth together - then drop that sound a couple of octaves. I don't consider this to be "chattering" teeth because there's at least a second between each single sound, and she's quite capable of stopping when there is no interaction. It's almost continuous throughout the interaction.

Oddly, [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kY0gclzC3pI) appears to be a very similar breed (if not the same) and the sound is *nothing* like that. The noise is much louder and the frequency *much* lower.

Is this a nervous behaviour she has developed, a potential quirk on the "chattering" of a similar breed or potentially the sign of something else? I have never known any other dog to make this sound so frequently (if at all).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The commonly used term for dogs repeatedly clapping their teeth is "chattering". Some breeds like greyhounds are more likely to develop this behavior than others.
It can be a sign of nervousness or anxiety, especially when paired with other body language clues like nervous shivering, wide "puppy eyes" or ears layed back against the skull. Some dogs also chatter during pleasant interactions like belly rubs. [Here's an example video](https://youtu.be/Wkeo_0_OcnM) where the chatter has a lower sound than many others I found.

If there is a longer pause between claps, I wouldn't consider it chattering. But without being able to see your dog, I can only speculate about its cause.

It could be caused by dental problems like misaligned teeth or a deformed jaw. I once saw a dog with a severely deformed jaw due to always laying in her dog bed and propping her head up on the rim in the same position. Her teeth clacked every tome she closed her mouth. Some dogs smack their lips while being pet. Maybe the sound could be caused by her smacking her lips but having misaligned teeth. You can see an example if lip smacking in the [second half of this video.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kMirei9-n18)

If the clapping is paired with "lip licking", then it could be considered a nervous or even aggressive gesture (made audible by an underlying dental problem). Dogs have different forms of licking their lips. If the tongue licks from the nose all the way to the corners of the mouth, it's most likely a nervous gesture. If only the very tip of the tongue rapidly pops out to lick only the tip of the nose, that's a more aggressive gesture, especially when paired with a wrinkled nose and a stiff posture. [Here's an example of the lip lick](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ytPGlvYjoA4) paired with avoidance signals (like looking away) that also happens in an interval of one second or more.

If the sound is so much lower than typical chattering, you should consider the possibility that it isn't caused by the teeth. Could it be her joints popping or some other sound?